# How can I get automatic properties in my class generated from XSD?

Tags: xsd.exe, xsd2code

Is there any way to get automatic properties in my class file that's generated from xsd? I am using Xsd2code and have tried the following command.

```
c:\xsd2code  q2test.xsd /n ContractXml /pl Net35 /ap[+] /xa[+]
```

It doesn't generate automatic properties. It generates something like this:

```
        public string AssetHdrId {
            get {
                return this.assetHdrIdField;
            }
            set {
                this.assetHdrIdField = value;
            }
        }

private string assetHdrIdField;
```

I want something simple like
                  public string AssetHdrId{get;set;}

I have around 355 properties in my class and I wanted to ask around before changing each one of them manually.

Comment: with automatic do you mean dynamic right?

Comment: by automatic, i mean a property without a backing field.

Comment: @abhi figured this out yet? same issue here

Comment: You can have a clue about this, checking this answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/25795077/1233788.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is late but might be useful for others if you are looking to generate properties for a class that do not contain backing fields using xsd2Code.  First, let's define a backing field. A default Properties in C# .net 2.0 was created using a private variable and public property (where the C# keyword value is the incoming string value):

```
private string _loanId;
public string LoanId
{
    get{ return _loanId; }
    set{ _loanId = value; }
}
```

This is very verbose and as the question poster describes can really bloat a class.  In C# 3.0, this changed and properties could be created without backing fields:

```
public string LoandId { get;set; }
```

I used xsd2Code++ V 4.2... and was able to set options that would enable property creation without a backing field.
Follow these steps:

1. Install [XSD2Code++](http://www.xsd2code.com/en-us/download.aspx) or [XSD2Code Community Edition](https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/)
2. Right click on an .xsd file
3. In the options panel, set the Application -> Target Framework to Net45
4. In the options panel, set the Settings -> PropertyParams -> Automatic Properties to true.

If you have auto update set, you'll see the backing properties disappear and be left with a much less verbose class.  You can also click the "generate" button to see the effects.

Cheers!

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the xsd2Code++ utility?

Comment: Sure, I added hyperlinks for both editions, in step 1. above.

Comment: Why isn't this answer accepted? Seems totally legit.