# xsd.exe Auto-Implemented Properties

Tags: c#, properties, xsd

Is it possible to force xsd.exe to generate auto-implemented properties instead of the ugly manually implemented code which xsd.exe generates?

```
public abstract partial class SomeClass {

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value {
        get {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why?  There's no real difference, or performance benefit.  It's just auto-generated code that you shouldn't be modifying anyway.

Comment: In case someone stumbles over this that does not need the get/set at all. The /fields option generates fields instead of properties and does not generate any getter or setters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems [XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx) does not support generating auto-implemented properties.

But there is an alternative: [Xsd2Code community edition](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/). From feature list:

> Support automatic properties when no special get or set is required.

Related answer: [XSDObjectGen.exe vs XSD.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3004884).

Comment: Beware that Xsd2Code has also a commercial side and some free features have jumped at least once unexpectedly from the free world to commercial. Do not rely on generated code private bits whichever way you go.